# Passing a function generically to c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto mapV(vector<T> v, F f) {
    vector<T> ret = {};
    for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        ret[i] = f(v[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main () {
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    vector<int> b = mapV(v, [](int &t){ return t*2; });
    for (int n : b) {
        cout << "is " << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this code compiles but when run generates a segfault. What is the correct way to accept a function generically using templates? I would like to define the structure of the function also, being able to say that I only accept a function that takes a T and returns a T, but I'm not quite sure how to express that.

I tried with `std::function<T(T)>` but that didn't work either

Comment: You're writing past the end of `ret` with `ret[i] = ...`.

Comment: ah, i need to push the elements instead?

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers, ask another question instead.

Comment: The answer posted doesnt answer my actual question "how do you pass a function generically to a c++ template"

Comment: Your lambda converts to a `std::function<int(int&)>`, which won't match `std::function<T(T)>` because of the reference parameter.

Comment: @aschepler feel free to write a more detailed answer which explains the different ways to pass a function as an argument to a template and i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<T> ret = {};
```

This creates an empty vector.

```
for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    ret[i] = f(v[i]);
```

This assigns something to the values in the vector `ret`. There are no existing values in the vector `ret`. There is no `ret[0]`. There is no `ret[1]`, and so on. This is undefined behavior. `operator[]` does not add new values to the vector, it only modifies existing ones.

Replace this with the `push_back()` method.

Comment: Ok that's helpful, do you know anything related to the title of the question? i.e. how to accept a function argument in a template? I'd like to restrict the function to only that of type T -> T. Right now I'm just accepting anything.

Comment: You can *assign* the parameter to a `std::function` variable. Alternatively, you can specialize the template using the appropriate type.

Comment: how? will the compiler type check the function properly?

Comment: properly using push_back() instead of the [] operator doesn't solve the actual problem being asked. This isn't a solution to "What is the correct way to accept a function generically using templates?"

Comment: Just assign it. If the type of the argument is wrong, the assignment will fail to compile.